# Add a Link Button on Each Click Event in VB

Tags: vb.net, onclick

I have a drop down list with a bunch of product names in it with an add button on the side. Everytime I press the add button, I want a Linkbutton to appear with the name of the product. I did the pnl.Controls.Add(New LinkButton), but it only adds one and then goes away next time I go to click. Here is the code I have right now that is making a LinkButton appear at click, just can't figure out how to alter the logic to add a new one each time.

```
Private Sub btnAddLinkedProjects_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddLinkedProjects.Click


    lbLinkedProject.Visible = True

    lbLinkedProject.Text = ddlParentProject.SelectedItem.Text


End Sub
```

I have a linkbutton in my designer that is set to invisible until it's clicked. Ultimately, when the link button of the project is clicked on, it fills in all of the fields like this

```
Private Sub lbLinkedProject_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbLinkedProject.Click

    Dim intParentRecID As Integer
    Dim pid As Project = Nothing
    Dim intCityState As Integer = 0
    Dim strState As String = ""
    Dim cs As nsCityState = Nothing

    intParentRecID = Integer.Parse(ddlParentProject.SelectedValue)

    pid = oDesignCon.getProjectByRecID(intParentRecID)
    If pid Is Nothing Then
    Else
        intCityState = pid.CityState
        cs = New nsCityState(intCityState)
        If cs Is Nothing Then
        Else
            strState = cs.StateShort
            Me.ddlAddState.SelectedValue = strState
            Call HandleAddStateChanged()
        End If

        Call nsLinqFormBinder.LoadContainer(Me.pnlCreateNewPID, pid)
        Me.ddlAddAssignTo.SelectedIndex = 0

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong if you just create new `LinkButton` as usual :

```
Private Sub btnAddLinkedProjects_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddLinkedProjects.Click
    'create & prepare new LinkButton'
    Dim newLinkedProject As New LinkButton
    newLinkedProject.Visible = True
    newLinkedProject.Text = ddlParentProject.SelectedItem.Text
    'register event handler'
    AddHandler newLinkedProject.Click, AddressOf Me.lbLinkedProject_Click
    'add the LinkButton to panel'
    pnl.Controls.Add(newLinkedProject)
End Sub
```

Comment: That works to add 1 link box, but when I go to select a new item from my drop down, it disappears (And there is nothing in my SelectedIndexChange for the drop down list even though it's acting like there is a clear)